# referencing pointers to character arrays, a strtok worked example

Tags: c, pointers, tokenize

I am working in C trying to tokenize an array and then store the tokens to a global array of strings. The catch is that i am trying to do this with pointers so I do not have to refrence the index of the array of strings. I know how big the array is supposed to be which is why it is easy to do it with the index, HOWEVER; i am trying to do this with just pointers. I don't know if this is possible so correct me here. Here is the code I have tried to implement but not been successful..

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

            char *cPayload2[PARAMS];

    void ReadIn2(char *input)
    {
        //Initialize the pointer to the 
        char *PayloadPtr;
        //start the parse
        char *token = strtok(input, "#");
        //pointer to an array of strings(pointers to character arrays)
        PayloadPtr = &cPayload2[0];

        while(token != NULL)
        {
```

This is the part in question, can i change the index of my global array with a clause like this. It seems I cannot print out the payload array with this.

```
            *PayloadPtr = token;
            //increment the index that the ptr refrences
            PayloadPtr++;
            //tokenize again
            token = strtok(NULL, "#");
        }

    }



    int main(void)
    {

        char input[] = "jsiUjd3762BNK==#KOIDKKkdkdwos==";

        ReadIn2(input);
```

This printout is bunked for some reason

```
        printf("%s\n",cPayload2[0]);
        printf("%s\n",cPayload2[1]);

        return 0;
    }
```

Any tips would be greatly appriciated.

Comment: This doesn't look quite right `*PayloadPtr = token;` as both variables are of type `char *` and you are dereferencing `PayloadPtr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char *PayloadPtr;
```

should be

```
char **PayloadPtr;
```

apart from that, your code is alright.

Comment: Thank you SIR, worked perfectly. This still confuses me a tad conceptually but I guess that is something that will come with time and exp.

Comment: @Recurrsion I thought it was just a typo, since the rest of the code works perfectly as intended. You should perhaps crank up the warning level of your compiler, that would have told you about the incompatible assignments.

Comment: WoW, Thanks Daniel; I turned it down originally because i did not think a higher level was necessary.

Comment: Well, it's not _necessary_, but unless your code produces tons of warnings even with toned down warning level, it helps find the problematic parts. Besides, it's nice to see your code compile warning free even at paranoid level.